# Angular $interval interrupting UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small $interval that runs every 10 seconds polling on a form possibly retrieving some additional messages.  When it kicks off it interferes with the form controls. If you are in a dropdown it will close the dropdown.  Just wondering if there is anyway to stop the $interval from interfering with the UI.

Comment: Can you add more code or even better a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Does your 'additional message' populate or modify a form field or affect validation state in any way?

Comment: @YosvelQuintero Or _even better_ a https://plnkr.co/

Comment: It will add a toastr if it comes back with any data and this is interrupting regardless of that.  As far as adding a fiddle.  I guess I could whip something up but it was more of a "Hey has anyone ever seen this"

Comment: Well great...I cannot duplicate the issue in a plunkr.  And there is just too much code to list here to be all that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution/problem.  Looks like BlockUi was automatically registering for every http call.  I added a config for it and only selectively using it where appropriate.  BlockUi and long-polling equals bad User Experience.